# Я хочу сделать фокус в картах для каждого элемента RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, google-maps-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть главная страница приложения с `RecyclerView`, все элементы записаны в `ArrayList`

```
private fun setItem(): ArrayList<Item> {
    //добавление элементов в RecyclerView
    var arrayList: ArrayList<Item> = ArrayList()
    arrayList.add(Item(R.drawable.koscmos,"")  
    arrayList.add(Item(R.drawable.bridge,"Latter")
    return arrayList
}
```

и есть вторая активность
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В которой есть кнопка к карте. При переходе к гугл картам есть маркер. И вот самый главный вопрос. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы для каждого объекта `RecyclerView` при переходе был и свой маркер (это я сделать смог), и приближение к этому маркеру.
Все данные передаются во вторую активность через `OnСlick`

```
val intent= Intent(this, secondAct::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("item", item?.get(position))
    startActivity(intent)
```

Все данные находятся в `item`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если у кого-то есть опыт работы с гугл картами или хоть какие-то идеи, рад выслушать.
Код гугл карт:

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private fun bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, vectorResId: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)?.run {
        setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        draw(canvas)
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(10.0f)
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f)
    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        val success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.mapstyle))
        if (!success) {
            Log.e("MapsActivity", "Style parsing failed.")
        }
    } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
        Log.e("MapsActivity", "Can't find style. Error: ", e)
    }

    val MuzeumOFCosmos = LatLng(54.5173381989551,36.23063585608777)
    val zoomLevel = 14.3f
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MuzeumOFCosmos, zoomLevel))
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(MuzeumOFCosmos).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(baseContext, R.drawable.drw)))
}
```

Comment: Ваша задача не очень ясна. Складывается впечатление, что весь текст из вопроса можно заменить на одну строку - "Как сделать приближение к точке на карте от гугл?" Это предположение верно?

Comment: Не совсем, мне нужно для отдельного элемента Recycler View отдельное приближение (я скорее всего не корректно выражаюсь, так как не знаю как объяснить точнее)

Comment: Попробуйте всё же как-то объяснить. Может быть вы имеете в виду анимацию перехода от одной активити к другой? Наверное нет... Наверное, вы всё же что-то с картами хотите сделать. Но при этом код с картами не показываете, а показываете, кажется, никак не относящийся к ним код со списком и активити с кнопкой. Может быть у вас нет кода с картами и вы просто приложение гугло-карт запускаете? И в нём надо что-то сделать? Тогда опять таки не ясно при чём тут весь код из вопроса. В общем - попробуйте максимально однозначно описать стоящую перед вами задачу.

Comment: Код карт я вставил. Попробую объяснить . У меня есть список достопримечательностей на главном экране. При нажатие есть переход на 2 активность с информацией(для каждого объекта Recycler View она разная). И я хотел бы сделать чтобы при нажатии  на кнопку "к карте" у меня показывались точка определенной достопримечательности с приближением к ней.

Comment: У вас, вроде, почти весь код есть. Просто замените захардкоженные координаты на переданные через Intent

Comment: хорошо, попробую,спасибо

Comment: я добавил этот код:  val item = intent.extras?.get("item") as Item
 ,val width=item.width. И у меня выкинуло эту ошибку                                                          
        Process: com.example.kalugaguide, PID: 19995
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type

Comment: Видимо `intent.extras?.get("item")` равно `null`. Смотрите что не так с передачей данных. Можете, наверное, это даже в этот вопрос добавить, но лучше новый задать. А ещё лучше - посмотреть тут, на сайте, в поиске как передавать данные между актвити.